# Troubles with a pipe and a fork

Tags: c, fork, pipe, execvp

I'm making a program that search files and sends it's results to other commands, like a pipe. ls | sort
When I run the program nothing happens.The problem I think is that the child's waits for the parent to stop writting in the SO buffer for starting the reading. 
This is what it sends to stdout and what the pipe should send to the other command.

```
    troneras@troneras-VirtualBox:~/Escritorio/busca.2012$ ./busca . -n . -print
    ./permisos.txt
    ./busca2.c
    ./mmap.pdf
    ./busca3.c~
    ./cuadernoso4.2011b.pdf
    ./busca.c~
    ./busca.c
    ./busca2.c~
    ./busca3.c
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

---

```
     if(!strcmp(argv[4],"-pipe"))
 {
int pipefd[2];
int pid,dummi;

if (pipe(pipefd)<0){
   perror("pipe");
   exit(1);
}

pid = fork();

if (pid<0){
   perror("fork");
   exit(1); 
}
if (pid == 0){//Child process    
   close(pipefd[1]);//The child is only reading from the pipe
   if(dup2(pipefd[0],0)!=0){perror("dup2");exit(1);}
   close(pipefd[0]);

       char *argumentos[argc-4];
   int j;
   for (j=5;j<argc;j++){
      argumentos[j-5]=argv[j];   
   }         
   argumentos[j-5]= NULL;    

   execvp(argv[5],argumentos);
   perror("execve: ");

}else{ //parent        
   close(pipefd[0]);
   if(dup2(pipefd[1],1)!=1){perror("dup2");exit(1);}
   close(pipefd[1]);

   while(count--){
      if(strcmp(files[count]->d_name,".") && strcmp(files[count]->d_name,"..")){               
         printf("%s/%s\n",argv[1],files[count]->d_name);                       
      free(files[count]);
   }

       wait(&dummi);
}

 }//end pipe                 
 free(files);
```

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms, does the child process keep running ("hangs"), or does it exit prematurely? In other words: Do you handle SIGCHLD and/or SIGPIPE?

Comment: It hangs. The process keeps running.

Comment: It works if I close the parent stdout after printing all. If I want later to write to the stdout, what should I do for opening that again?

Comment: In that case, it appears the execd program waits for a character (or EOF) on its stdin. Closing the pipe should do the trick. (If you need the stdout filedescriptor, you should have saved it before dupping pipefd onto it) Beware tat *if* the child exits, the parent will get a SIGCHLD (and a SIGPIPE if it attempts to write into the semi-closed pipe)

Comment: Ok, now it's doing crazy things. I have a printf("PIPE\n"); before making the pipe, if I comment the line the program stops working.

Comment: It is better to use stderr for diagnostics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW There is no reason to duplicate the argv[] array. Instead of

```
   char *argumentos[argc-4];
   int j;
   for (j=5;j<argc;j++){
      argumentos[j-5]=argv[j];   
   }         
   argumentos[j-5]= NULL;    

   execvp(argv[5],argumentos);
```

You could just as well do

```
   execvp(argv[5],argv+5);
```

Comment: Wow thank's. I love those details. It actually works. I had to make a fflush before close the stdout. Now it works!